# MPMoviePlayerController fail to play audio

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmediaitem

I use MPMoviePlayerController to play a list of audio streams from url. I use the following code to init the player

```
self.player = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
```

and later use the following code to set and reset contentUrl:

```
self.player.contentURL = url;
[self.player prepareToPlay];
```

but sometimes, not every time, it fails to play audio, post MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification directly and gives following userInfo

```
{
    MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey = 1;
    error = "Error Domain=MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-11828 \"Cannot Open\" UserInfo=0xee7bf20 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Open}";
}
```

anyone knows why?

Comment: Where you able to solve this "Cannot Open" issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead of MPMoviePlayerController.

I had seen such issues before when streaming audio with MPMoviePlayerController. AVPlayer is the more appropriate one for this task.